# "This movie (has given/has been giving) me a headache, I am going to bed now" which one is it?

Tags: present-perfect, perfect-continuous

> "This movie **(has given/has been giving)** me a headache, I am going to bed now"

Which one is it?

I personally feel like both could work. I also think that there needs to be more context. But even if that's the case, which one is more correct? Or which one should I choose if there are no other options?

Comment: You might consider changing the punctuation after "headache" to avoid the comma splice.

Answer (score 1):

*Has given* is much more natural (you finish watching and realise that you now have a headache).

Even if you had been aware of the headache coming on while you were watching, I don't find the continuous tense particularly idiomatic.

Answer (score -1):

Both of them are fine. The nuance between them is very small, so you don't need to worry.

Comment: I don't think the continuous version is very idiomatic. It should definitely be avoided by non-native speakers (who should *by default* avoid Perfect ***and*** Continuous forms except in contexts where they *know* they're needed).